# Why is the return type of std::reverse_iterator::operator[] unspecified?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, language-lawyer

I was wondering, why, in C++, the return type of [`std::reverse_iterator::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/operator_at) is left unspecified. Shouldn't it be `std::reverse_iterator::reference`?

Comment: @Columbo Can you provide a link to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually a superfluous relaxation; As of [LWG 448](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#448) and [LWG 299](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-closed.html#299) (over [N3066](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3066.html)), which are incorporated in C++11, iterators' return types of `operator[]` shall be convertible to `reference`. The original LWG issue that introduced this underspecification ([386](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#386)) was unfortunately resolved before the one that changed the requirements on the return type of `operator[]`.

Since the return type of iterators' `operator[]` is now mandated to be convertible to `reference`, the return type of `reverse_iterator::operator[]` can clearly be just `reference` - and it is, in both libc++ and libstdc++.

Comment: ...and MSVC too. Want to file an LWG issue?